How to use Github Rest API properly
I am doing my college assignment project. But am not able to find these data using github api:
login: Their Github user ID
name: Their full name
company: The company they work at. Clean up company names. At least make sure:
They're trimmed of whitespace
Leading @ symbol is stripped (Note: ONLY the first one is stripped)
They are converted to UPPERCASE
location: The city they are in
email: Their email address
hireable: Whether they are open to being hired
bio: A short bio about them
public_repos: The number of public repositories they have
followers: The number of followers they have
following: The number of people they are following
created_at: When they joined Github
Given below in my code which I used and get the json file

json

import requests
import 

query = "location:Bengaluru+followers:>100"
url = f"https://api.github.com/search/users?q={query}&sort=followers&order=desc"

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()  # Parse the JSON response

formatted_json = json.dumps(data, indent=4)  # Convert the JSON object to a formatted string

# Save the formatted JSON string to a file
F = open("user_data.json", "w")
F.write(formatted_json)
F.close()

I want to find the values of all the columns asked using GITHUB REST API

Here is the simple code to fetch user details(As you mentioned), please follow the comment of the code for the explanation,
Sample Code:
"""
Remember GitHub has a Rate limit for user endpoints which is 100 queries per day for unauthenticated users,
if you want more than a thousand then use GitHub pat token with API for better results with more queries
just add this header, {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {Token is here}"
}
API doc: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/quickstart?apiVersion=2022-11-28
"""

import requests
import json

url = 'https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location:Bengaluru+followers:>100'
resp = requests.get(url).json()

count = resp['total_count']
ranges = int(count / 30 + 1) #each page contains 30 results so we need to adjust the range value for loops
for i in range(1, ranges):
    get_search = requests.get(f'https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location:Bengaluru+followers:>100&page={i}').json()

    for i in get_search['items']:
        name_u = i['login']
        get_details = requests.get(f'https://api.github.com/users/{name_u}').json() #this is the user endpoint where user data will be fetched from
        name = [f"ID: {get_details['id']}", f"Login: {get_details['login']}", f"Full Name: {get_details['name']}", f"Company: {get_details['company']}", f"Location: {get_details['location']}", f"Email: {get_details['email']}", f"Bio: {get_details['bio']}", f"Twitter username: {get_details['twitter_username']}", f"Public repo: {get_details['public_repos']}", f"Public gist: {get_details['public_gists']}", f"Follower: {get_details['followers']}", f"Following: {get_details['following']}", f"Account Created: {get_details['created_at']}"]
        print(name)

Sample output:
['ID: 547147', 'Login: knadh', 'Full Name: Kailash Nadh', 'Company: Zerodha', 'Location: Bengaluru', 'Email: None', 'Bio: Hobbyist developer | CTO @zerodha | Volunteer @fossunited @rainmatter-foundation  @indic-archive ', 'Twitter username: None', 'Public repo: 67', 'Public gist: 15', 'Follower: 9576', 'Following: 0', 'Account Created: 2011-01-04T15:32:55Z']
['ID: 12962887', 'Login: sadanandpai', 'Full Name: Sadanand Pai', 'Company: Atlassian', 'Location: Bengaluru', 'Email: None', 'Bio: Frontend Engineer | UI Dev | Learner', 'Twitter username: sadanand_pai', 'Public repo: 44', 'Public gist: 2', 'Follower: 2825', 'Following: 8', 'Account Created: 2015-06-19T06:35:46Z']
['ID: 29688323', 'Login: DeekshithSN', 'Full Name: Deekshith SN', 'Company: None', 'Location: Bengaluru', 'Email: None', 'Bio: A DevOps engineer with a knack for Automation and a proven track record in maintaining and administering DevOps process.\r\n', 'Twitter username: deekshithsn', 'Public repo: 69', 'Public gist: 4', 'Follower: 1730', 'Following: 1', 'Account Created: 2017-06-25T11:11:21Z']
['ID: 34368930', 'Login: collabnix', 'Full Name: Collabnix', 'Company: @collabnix', 'Location: Bengaluru', 'Email: None', "Bio: Collabnix is a popular blogging site and DevOps community founded by Docker Captain Ajeet Singh Raina. It's a DevOps community of 9.6k Slack members.", 'Twitter username: collabnix', 'Public repo: 268', 'Public gist: 16', 'Follower: 1657', 'Following: 1', 'Account Created: 2017-12-08T09:28:02Z']
['ID: 9478845', 'Login: probelalkhan', 'Full Name: Belal Khan', 'Company: Simplified Coding', 'Location: Bengaluru, India', 'Email: None', 'Bio: Belal Khan is an experienced technologist with a passion for developing innovative solutions. ', 'Twitter username: probelalkhan', 'Public repo: 157', 'Public gist: 0', 'Follower: 1571', 'Following: 0', 'Account Created: 2014-10-31T09:42:00Z']
['ID: 22263782', 'Login: krishnadey30', 'Full Name: Krishna Kumar Dey', 'Company: SpotDraft', 'Location: Bengaluru', 'Email: None', "Bio: Senior-SDE SpotDraft | Ex-SDE Amazon Luxembourg | GSoC'20 Mentor @ Chapel | GSoC'19 @ Chapel | Software Developer ", 'Twitter username: krishnadey30', 'Public repo: 33', 'Public gist: 18', 'Follower: 1539', 'Following: 15', 'Account Created: 2016-09-17T20:09:40Z']
['ID: 19903539', 'Login: Shubham0812', 'Full Name: Shubham Kr. Singh', 'Company: iOS Developer @ Dailyrounds / Marrow', 'Location: Bengaluru,Karnataka', 'Email: None', 'Bio: iOS developer by profession. Loves iOS development, traveling, and solving problems. Also a UI / UX enthusiast.\r\n', 'Twitter username: shubham_iosdev', 'Public repo: 61', 'Public gist: 61', 'Follower: 1437', 'Following: 6', 'Account Created: 2016-06-13T08:30:04Z']
['ID: 77569653', 'Login: SamirPaulb', 'Full Name: Samir Paul', 'Company: National Institute of Technology Durgapur', 'Location: Bengaluru, Karnataka, India', 'Email: None', "Bio: NIT Dgp ECE'24 | Competitive Programmer | Back-End Developer | Former Intern at NITI Aayog", 'Twitter username: SamirPaulb', 'Public repo: 65', 'Public gist: 18', 'Follower: 1299', 'Following: 98', 'Account Created: 2021-01-17T09:54:08Z']

Let me know if this is what you want
